# Difference between query() and ajax() in the select2

Tags: jquery-select2

1. When these functions will be called
2. can i control ajax() calling from the query().

I had a problem:
When i return multiple values from the createSearchChoice() i am getting error while i use tokenSeperator option.

I had a logic in createSearchChoice(), where selected results from the ajax is stored to a local storage and will be shown on the next search. Here i am returning multiple values like [{id:"test", text:"test"},{id:"test1", text:"test1"}] where tokenizer is failing

But when i return single value {id:"test", text:"text"} from createSearchChocie, tokenizeSeperator option of select2 is working fine.

Let me know can i move the logic of local storage to the query() and return only a single value in the createSearchChoice().

Answer (score 0):

> When i return multiple values from the createSearchChoice() i am getting error while i use tokenSeperator option.

The problem here is that `createSearchChoice` is only allowed to [return a single object](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/2eea4a486a8d3d34c87cf53cb3a69fb7aa21ff48/select2.js#L1832) in Select2 3.5.x. So by returning multiple objects, Select2 isn't prepared for it and is triggering an exception (because the properties don't exist). `createSearchChoice` is designed to return *a single option* representing the *current search term* so it can be tokenized and selected. If you're looking to return multiple options, you should be looking at a custom `query` method.

> Let me know can i move the logic of local storage to the query()

[The `query` option](http://select2.github.io/select2/#data) takes a set of query parameters (including the search term, page number, and the callback function) and executes a search query based on them. All of the default search methods of Select2 use the same `query` method, just some of them (`<select>` element, `data` option, and `ajax` option) provide default `query` methods so you don't have to.

You can access these default implementations using the `window.Select2.query` object.

- `window.Select2.ajax` - Contains the default implementation for the `ajax` option.
- `window.Select2.local` - Contains the default implementation for the `data` option.
- `window.Select2.tags` - Contains the default implementation for the `tags` option.

Keep in mind that these only work with a `<input />` element, you cannot provide custom query methods in Select2 3.5.x with a `<select>`. That is only allowed in Select2 4.0.0 and later.

So that means that you can have your own custom `query` method which calls the original `ajax` method and still uses it for calls where the local data has not been cached.

```
function query (options) {
  var localCache = {}; // whatever you use for your caching

  return function (params) {
    var term = params.term || '';

    // check if the query has been cached
    if (term in localCache) {
      return localCache[term];
    }

    // call the original `ajax` query
    return localCache[term] = window.Select2.query.ajax(params);
  }
}
```

Comment: With select2 4.0, the last line (`window.Select2.query.ajax(params);`) throws an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`